# CSS table 'borrows' style from another table

Tags: html, css

I'm styling 2 tables, one for desktop/tablet and one for mobile.
My problem lies that depending what table i define first, is the one that borrows some of the styles from other table.

css:

```
table.table-payments{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;  
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-type-2);

}

table.table-payments > tr, thead, td, th {
    padding:5px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--brand-light-gray-2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: var(--text-size);
    height: 60px;
}


table.payments-mobile > tr, td, th{
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
}
table.payments-mobile > tbody{
    background-color: var(--brand-white);
    margin:5px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-type-2);
}
```

[image showing chrome style inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7RPl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining styles for elements generically in your css. You should be defining them more specifically, declaring the specific table for each element. So instead of:

```
table.payments-mobile > tr,
td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
}
```

You should do:

```
table.payments-mobile > tr,
table.payments-mobile > td,
table.payments-mobile > th {
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
}
```